# PowerShell invoke commands failing

Tags: powershell, active-directory-group

This powershell is designed to add a user to either the Admin, Remote Desktop Users/User group depending on AD Group.

I tested on a Windows 7 Workstation and it worked great.  When I try on a Windows 2012 Server it only adds the user to "Remote Desktop User" and not "Users"  Advice please:

```
  $user = $UserName
$group = "Domain Admins"
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select - ExpandProperty SamAccountName  


If ($members -contains $user) {
        $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$TargetServer/Administrators,group"
        $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$UserName,user"
        $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
        Start-Sleep -s 3
        invoke-command -ComputerName $TargetServer {net localgroup administrators}

 } Else {
        $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$TargetServer/Remote Desktop Users,group"
        $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$UserName,user"
        $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
        Start-Sleep -s 3
        invoke-command -ComputerName $TargetServer {net localgroup Remote Desktop Users}

       $AdminGroup = [ADSI]"WinNT://$TargetServer/Users,group"
        $User = [ADSI]"WinNT://$DomainName/$UserName,user"
        $AdminGroup.Add($User.Path)
        Start-Sleep -s 3
        invoke-command -ComputerName $TargetServer {net localgroup Users}   


}
```

Comment: It appears that the the add to "Users" group is not working for Workstations either.

Comment: Ok weird.  If I reverse the "Remote Desktop User"  and "User" code blocks, it works on both Server and Workstation.  Weird but resolved.  I would like to know why if anyone has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok weird. If I reverse the "Remote Desktop User" and "User" code blocks, it works on both Server and Workstation. Weird but resolved. I would like to know why if anyone has an answer.

Comment: Ok change 2 revision 4.  It is not working.  It works intermittently :(  Thoughts please